# Where can I find PalmOS 3.5 developer tools? Palm's site no longer publishes them

Tags: sdk, palm-os, palm

The hard drive on one of my PCs crashed that had the installers for the various PalmOS 3.5 dev tools for my old Palm IIIc and VIIx.  It seems now Palm has taken down its downloads of everything pre-Garnet.

Can anyone provide the files or links to the SDK, CDK 4.0.3, POSE emulator, and whatever else is out there?

Comment: I looked around too but nothing either. You would probably have to email Palm in order to get it. Perhaps someone else who has it can upload it to you.

Comment: Why can't you use the Garnet tools?  Are you worried about accidentally using an API that doesn't exist on older systems?

Comment: I'm only familiar with pre-Garnet, so I wasn't aware Garnet SDK would work to compile PalmOS 3.5/4.0 platform.

Comment: It'll be fine.  If that weren't the case, it would be very difficult for developers to target Garnet *and* older Palm OS versions with the same binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After jamesdlin pointed out that there is some SDK overlap with Garnet and pre-Garnet devices, I found that these installers are actually still available for download, but at a new site under Garnet support.

http://www.accessdevnet.com/index.php/ACCESS-SDKs/View-category.html

They still have the SDK 5.0 R3 and CDK 4.03/6.01 listed.

Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

The Palm OS 3.5 SDK is included in CodeWarrior for Palm OS V7, IIRC.  Most of those are also on the CodeWarrior discs, although they weren't allowed to actually ship ROM images.

Answer (score 0):

I upload it here for everyone, Palm was very good device.
http://download.hellshare.cz/palmos351-en-sdk-win-zip/4212237/